# Why do I have to click button twice before event fires?

Tags: javascript, class, events, addeventlistener

A simple multiple choice quiz with one problem I can't solve. At first When I clicked the 'next question' button the next question and answers didn't show only when clicked a second time the next question and answers showed.
When I placed runningQuestion++ above questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
like I did in the nextQuestion function the initial problem is solved but reappears after the last question when you are asked to try again. Only now when you click 'try again' now ofcourse it skips the first question.

```js
class Question {
  constructor(question, answers, correct) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correct = correct;
  }

  displayAnswers() {
    document.querySelector('.question').innerHTML = `<div class="q1">${this.question}</div>`
    let i = 0
    let answers = this.answers
    for (let el of answers) {
      let html = `<div class="name" id=${i}>${el}</div>`
      document.querySelector('.answers').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
      i++
    }
  }

}

const q1 = new Question('What\'s the capitol of Rwanda?', ['A: Dodoma', 'B: Acra', 'C: Kigali'], 2);
const q2 = new Question('What\'s is the square root of 0?', ["A: Not possible", 'B: 0', 'C: 1'], 1);
const q3 = new Question('Who was Rome\'s first emperor?', ['A: Tiberius', 'B: Augustus', 'C: Marcus Aurelius'], 1);

const questions = [q1, q2, q3];
let runningQuestion;
let gamePlaying;

init()

document.querySelector('.button1').addEventListener('click', nextQuestion)

function nextQuestion(e) {
  console.log(e.target)

  if (gamePlaying === true && runningQuestion <= questions.length - 1) {
    clearAnswers()
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Next Question'
    runningQuestion++
    questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
  }
  if (runningQuestion >= questions.length - 1) {
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Try again!'
    runningQuestion = 0
  }
}

function clearAnswers() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(el => {
    el.remove()
  })

}

document.querySelector('.button2').addEventListener('click', resetGame)

function resetGame() {
  document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Next Question'
  clearAnswers()
  runningQuestion = 0
  questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
}

function init() {
  gamePlaying = true;
  runningQuestion = 0;
  questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 100px auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.question {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: rgb(102, 0, 0);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.answers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(102, 0, 0);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.button1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: rgb(102, 0, 0);
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.button2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-style: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="question"></div>
    <div class="answers"></div>
    <button type="button" class="button1">Next Question</button>
    <button type="button" class="button2">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I removed my answer, since it wasn't clear enough. And the reason I wasn't clear enough is that your question also isn't. You posted a lot of JS. But we can't do anything with it/play with it to fully understand what's happening. To get an answer that really fits your needs, you should create what we call a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1913729) right here in your question so that we can run your code, reproduce the problem and help you fix it with more context

Comment: I hope more readable/understandable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the current version is that you reset `runningQuestion` to `0`, and when clicking on the button, you execute `nextQuestion`, which, as the name implies, goes to the next question (`runningQuestion++`).

I see 2 ways of solving this. Either the "easy" way, by resetting `runningQuestion` to `-1` so that it goes to `0`:

```js
class Question{constructor(e,s,t){this.question=e,this.answers=s,this.correct=t}displayAnswers(){document.querySelector(".question").innerHTML=`<div class="q1">${this.question}</div>`;let e=0,s=this.answers;for(let t of s){let s=`<div class="name" id=${e}>${t}</div>`;document.querySelector(".answers").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",s),e++}}}const q1=new Question("What's the capitol of Rwanda?",["A: Dodoma","B: Acra","C: Kigali"],2),q2=new Question("What's is the square root of 0?",["A: Not possible","B: 0","C: 1"],1),q3=new Question("Who was Rome's first emperor?",["A: Tiberius","B: Augustus","C: Marcus Aurelius"],1),questions=[q1,q2,q3];let runningQuestion,gamePlaying;init(),document.querySelector(".button1").addEventListener("click",nextQuestion);
/* Nothing changed above */

function nextQuestion(e) {
  runningQuestion++; // <---------------------------------------------------------

  if (gamePlaying === true && runningQuestion <= questions.length - 1) {
    clearAnswers();
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Next Question';
    questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers();
  }
  if (runningQuestion >= questions.length - 1) {
    document.querySelector('.button1').textContent = 'Try again!';
    runningQuestion = -1; // <-----------------------------------------------------
  }
}

/* Nothing changed below */
function clearAnswers(){document.querySelectorAll(".name").forEach(e=>{e.remove()})}function resetGame(){document.querySelector(".button1").textContent="Next Question",clearAnswers(),runningQuestion=0,questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()}function init(){gamePlaying=!0,runningQuestion=0,questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()}document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click",resetGame);
```

```css
/* Same CSS as yours */ *{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}.container{display:flex;width:400px;height:auto;margin:100px auto;align-items:center;flex-direction:column}.question{margin-top:40px;color:#600;font-size:1.4rem}.answers{display:flex;flex-direction:column;margin-top:10px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px}.name{margin-top:20px;cursor:pointer;color:#600;font-size:1.2rem}.button1{margin-top:50px;border-style:none;width:350px;height:50px;font-size:1.4rem}ul>li{list-style-type:none;margin-top:10px;font-size:1.2rem;color:#600;height:30px;cursor:pointer;display:block}.button2{margin-top:20px;border-style:none;width:350px;height:50px;font-size:1.4rem}
```

```html
<!-- Same HTML as yours --> <div class="container"> <div class="question"></div><div class="answers"></div><button type="button" class="button1">Next Question</button> <button type="button" class="button2">Reset</button></div>
```

or another way, which I find cleaner. A problem you can run into with your current code, is that if you have other things to keep track of, like a score, for example, you might forget to reset them as well, inside your `nextQuestion` function. And if you add other stuff, you'll need to reset them in multiple places in your code.

What I would do is simply reuse the `resetGame` function to reset everything:

```js
class Question{constructor(e,s,t){this.question=e,this.answers=s,this.correct=t}displayAnswers(){document.querySelector(".question").innerHTML=`<div class="q1">${this.question}</div>`;let e=0,s=this.answers;for(let t of s){let s=`<div class="name" id=${e}>${t}</div>`;document.querySelector(".answers").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",s),e++}}}const q1=new Question("What's the capitol of Rwanda?",["A: Dodoma","B: Acra","C: Kigali"],2),q2=new Question("What's is the square root of 0?",["A: Not possible","B: 0","C: 1"],1),q3=new Question("Who was Rome's first emperor?",["A: Tiberius","B: Augustus","C: Marcus Aurelius"],1),questions=[q1,q2,q3];let runningQuestion,gamePlaying;
/* Nothing changed above */

const btn1 = document.querySelector('.button1');

init();

btn1.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

function isLastQuestion() { return runningQuestion >= questions.length - 1; }

function onButtonClick() {
  if (gamePlaying === true && !isLastQuestion()) {
    runningQuestion++;
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    resetGame();
  }
}

function displayQuestion() {
    clearAnswers();
    btn1.textContent = isLastQuestion() ? 'Try again' : 'Next Question';
    questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers();
}

/* Nothing changed below */
function clearAnswers(){document.querySelectorAll(".name").forEach(e=>{e.remove()})}function resetGame(){document.querySelector(".button1").textContent="Next Question",clearAnswers(),runningQuestion=0,questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()}function init(){gamePlaying=!0,runningQuestion=0,questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()}document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click",resetGame);function init(){gamePlaying=true;runningQuestion = 0;questions[runningQuestion].displayAnswers()}
```

```css
/* Same CSS as yours */ *{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}.container{display:flex;width:400px;height:auto;margin:100px auto;align-items:center;flex-direction:column}.question{margin-top:40px;color:#600;font-size:1.4rem}.answers{display:flex;flex-direction:column;margin-top:10px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px}.name{margin-top:20px;cursor:pointer;color:#600;font-size:1.2rem}.button1{margin-top:50px;border-style:none;width:350px;height:50px;font-size:1.4rem}ul>li{list-style-type:none;margin-top:10px;font-size:1.2rem;color:#600;height:30px;cursor:pointer;display:block}.button2{margin-top:20px;border-style:none;width:350px;height:50px;font-size:1.4rem}
```

```html
<!-- Same HTML as yours --> <div class="container"> <div class="question"></div><div class="answers"></div><button type="button" class="button1">Next Question</button> <button type="button" class="button2">Reset</button></div>
```